# find transaction id of spring @Transactional

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am using @Transactional to manage the transaction

```
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public List<FooBo> save(Foo foo, Foo foo2) {
    logger.debug(() -> String.format("FooService.save()"));
    repository.save(foo);
    return repository1.save(foo2);
  }
```

I am unable to find transaction id while using `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionInfo()`

is there any other way? (if Spring maintaining the Unique Id of transaction)

**Update**:
My Scenario is that I want to put some information on static context based on transaction id. And after transaction commit need that information.

**For example** .. based on transaction ID, I want to put some objects in map in static context and after commit need to utilize these objects.. that is what I am thinking

Comment: What is a Transaction ID?

Comment: @AlanHay I am assuming that every transaction has its unique Id. I need to track each transaction.

Comment: Why do you need to track the transactions? What is your use case. here. Spring doesn't generate anything it leaves it to the underlying tx solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated my question. thanks

Comment: The transaction ID is the name of your transaction's bean.

Comment: @akuma8 , but it is same for multiple thread. if I use this to save some information in static context, obviously for multiple thread , result would be wrong

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could maybe do this is to create the Transaction yourself in the method by getting the Transaction Manager through your Spring Application Context and calling `getTransaction()` with a new  `TransactionDefinition` that contains a custom ID that you can control. You'll then be able to use the ID you've just set for your logic but you just then manually `commit()` or `rollback()` the transaction when you're done

Comment: What would be the TransactionDefinition "custom ID that you can control" ? I can't find any class attribute matching that description

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem as you do and seeing that there is no solution, what might work is that each Spring transaction is bound to a thread, so use either thread-local storage, or use unique thread-id as the key.
For these solutions, you have to be sure that on commit the TX specific info will be cleared from the thread local storage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().hashCode()

to get Unique Id of transaction